# Interpreted string literals in Go

Tags: go, coding-style

It's frequently nice to write long, informative strings for log messages or stderr messages.  Python handles this with comma separated string literals, like:

```
log.warn("The operation failed on the %d iteration. "
         "Resumed on the %d iteration.",
         failed, resumed)
```

Go appears to have a solution for raw string literals, by using back quotes but I can't find any style guide for interpreted string literals.  Am I missing something or is there no option but to use a variable? E.g.

```
msg := fmt.Sprintf("The operation failed on the %d iteration. ", failed)
msg += fmt.Sprintf("Resumed on the %d iteration.", resumed)
log.println(msg)
```

Comment: What you are really asking is how you would continue a statement on the next line of the source file. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't see how your python example would even work. Here's something similar:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.warn("foo %d", "bar %d", 1,2)
```

causes:

```
 TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Second, in Go, you have a few options:

Multi-line strings:

```
msg := fmt.Sprintf(`The operation failed on the %d iteration. 
            Resumed on the %d iteration.`, 2, 3)
log.Println(msg)
```

But this will result in a multiline message.

Another option:

```
  log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("The operation failed on the %d iteration. ", failed), 
              fmt.Sprintf("Resumed on the %d iteration.", resumed))
```

which both looks better and will probably be faster than string concatenation.

Comment: I slipped an unwanted comma into my Python example.  Drop the one between the two strings and it'll work. Your Sprintf example is nice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `+`:

```
fmt.Printf("The operation failed on the %d iteration. "+
    "Resumed on the %d iteration.",
    failed, resumed,
)
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/nkRMcYdOT4).

There are examples in the standard library of using `+` for that, most of them in tests. [Example](http://golang.org/src/pkg/mime/mediatype_test.go#L239). For more examples see this search request: [http://golang.org/search?q=%22\%2B\n](http://golang.org/search?q=%22%5C%2B%5Cn).